# Best and most lightweight javascript for play sound in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2, soundjs

I want implement to my web-app sound notifications with volume control and selection of sounds. So when user will receive example message then webapp execute selected sound with currently set volume level.

Requirements:

- No jQuery dependency
- Lightweigt as possible
- Compatible with all mobile browsers

I have found some javascripts:

- [soundmanager2](https://github.com/scottschiller/soundmanager2/)
- [soundjs](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS)

I have not any experience with those scripts so I wanna ask if is there any better solution or which mentioned script is better?
Thanks for any opinion.

Comment: **Primarily opinion-based**, it's right there in the question

Comment: True, this is asking for opinion and not a code question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoundJS is the best and works everywhere, but I'm biased because I work on it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the html5 `Audio` tag.

You are going to find it difficult to find one solution that will work on ALL browsers.

Comment: Yes sure soundmanager2 and soundjs are working with this tag. But I wanna know some experience or opinions...